# How to add Tickmarks to RasterImage Plot?

Tags: r, image, plot

How do I add tickmarks to the x- and y-axis of the following RasterImage Plot? The image resolution is 768x512. The x-axis should span from 0 to 768, evenly spaced tickmarks. The y-axis should span from 0 to 512, evenly spaced tickmarks.

```
library(EBImage)
library(png)
f = system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")
img<-readPNG(f)
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), asp=NA)
rasterImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Output:

[image]

I tried adding axes manually with `plot.window(xlim=c(0, ncol(img)), ylim=c(0, nrow(img)), asp=1)`.

I also tried `plot.window(xlim=c(0,1),ylim = (0,1), asp=NA, axes=T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will add axis ticks to the x and y axes:

```
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,700,100)/768, labels=seq(0,700,100))
axis(side=2, at=seq(0,500,100)/512, labels=seq(0,500,100), las=1)
```

[image]

To have the axis lines right at the edge of the picture, use the `pos` argument:

```
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,700,100)/768, labels=seq(0,700,100), pos=0)
axis(side=2, at=seq(0,500,100)/512, labels=seq(0,500,100), las=1, pos=0)
```

[image]